# How do I leave email addresses in appropriate fields (to, cc) when using reply all in Apple Mail?

Tags: osx-mavericks, apple-mail, email-filter

This has been bugging me for a while and there seems to be no answers online that I can find. I am running Mac OSX Mavericks and Apple Mail. When I click reply all for any particular email the default is to place all email addresses in the email in the cc field except for who I am replying to. I do not want this behavior as I typically do not want to cc everyone else.

I use to and cc fields to rank importance of reading emails and expect that others do the same. It is important to retain this on emails with several participants. Currently I am manually moving the email addresses every time I reply all to an email.

How can I change this default setting?

Answer (score 1):

The OS X default is to only place the target of your email in the to field and all the rest in the cc field. However, as you say, this isn't always the best solution. I used to run an AppleScript to copy all addresses in the cc field into the to field but I now use Keyboard Maestro to do the same because it's easier to fix whenever Apple breaks it with an upgrade...

I have a macro in my Keyboard Maestro menu which selects the cc field, types cmd-a, cmd-x, shift-tab, right-arrow, cmd-y.

It all fails if I don't want everyone in the to field so I end up doing it manually anyway!

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but still doesn't get what I'm looking to do. I can't believe apple doesn't have a setting for this. I need to target multiple people in my reply. Thx for the tip!